# How do I parse data with url.parse(...)?

Tags: node.js

I found this sample code of a nodeJS server. I don't understand what this line of code does, what is the true for:

```
var urlParts = url.parse(req.url, true)
```

The following line is also unclear to me. Why is it neccessairy to write data.txt?

```
fs.writeFileSync("data.txt", data);
```

SERVER

```
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost'
  });

  var urlParts = url.parse(req.url, true),
      data = urlParts.query.data;

  fs.writeFileSync("data.txt", data);

  res.end("OK");
});
```

Comment: in `url.parse` true enables parsing of the query string http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line `require('url').parse(req.url, true)` return URL object (see bottom), and pass true as the second argument to also parse the query.

- **href :** The full URL that was originally parsed. Both the protocol and host are lowercased.
- **protocol :** The request protocol, lowercased.
- **host :** The full lowercased host portion of the URL, including port information.
- **auth :** The authentication information portion of a URL.
- **hostname :** Just the lowercased hostname portion of the host.
- **port :** The port number portion of the host.
- **pathname :** The path section of the URL, that comes after the host and before the query, including the initial slash if present.
- **search :** The 'query string' portion of the URL, including the leading question mark.
- **path :** Concatenation of pathname and search.
- **query :** Either the 'params' portion of the query string, or a querystring-parsed object.
- **hash :** The 'fragment' portion of the URL including the pound-sign.

See : http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html